# Posting MySQL encrypt in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

Hi I'm trying to post values from a page into a MySQL DB, however the password field has to be encrypted via the encrypt command.

So far I have this -

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `ftpuser` (`userid`, `passwd`, `uid`, `gid`, `homedir`, `shell`, `count`, `accessed`, `modified`) 
VALUES
('$_POST[userid]', encrypt(".$_POST['passwd']."),'$_POST[uid]','$_POST[gid]','$_POST[homedir]','$_POST[shell]','$_POST[count]','$_POST[accessed]','$_POST[modified]')";
```

The script connects to the DB fine, however the output is "Error: Unknown column 'test34' in 'field list'"

Thanks.

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: Are you sure this is the code that produces the error?

Comment: You haven't wrapped the value you are trying to encrypt in quotes so it's trying to encrypt the column called <whatever your password is>

Comment: @BigRabbit , hey there. Sorry if it wasn't clear- I'm trying to post something like encrypt('secret') to my DB but through PHP. My question being how would I go about doing so? As in my snippet above I'm getting errors. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
encrypt(".$_POST['passwd'].")
```

doesn't have any quotes around the value, so mysql gets it as a column name. For example, if your password is test123, this part of query would look like:

```
encrypt(test123)
```

while what you really need is

```
encrypt('test123')
```

So, you can fix this problem just by adding single quotes

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `ftpuser` (`userid`, `passwd`, `uid`, `gid`, `homedir`, `shell`, `count`, `accessed`, `modified`) 
VALUES
('$_POST[userid]', encrypt('".$_POST['passwd']."'),'$_POST[uid]','$_POST[gid]','$_POST[homedir]','$_POST[shell]','$_POST[count]','$_POST[accessed]','$_POST[modified]')"
```

**However, there is much bigger problem** in this code. You don't escape the values, therefore open an SQL injection. Just think what would happen if your password contains a single quote, such as test'123:

```
encode('test'123')
```

This is obviously a syntax error. In fact it allows anyone to execute arbitrary SQL expressions by crafting special parameters in $_POST.

So what you really should do is either escape everything you put into query or use PDO with placeholders. Check for example, this tutorial http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PDO-Positional-and-Named-Placeholders-P551.html

Comment: Thanks man! Not too worried about SQLi though (yet) as this just in a authenticated backend. 

Thank you again!

Comment: Not worrying about SQL Injection is wrong attitude. Even if you're 100% sure this service won't mistakently become public (are you?), so no real harm will be done, you still need to make it reliable. And I have given you an example how this will fail if the password contains a single quote sign.